# List all Mongoid models in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, rails-console

I want to list all the models which have a respective collection in my mongodb database? I'm using `mongoid` gem for for MongoDB.

I would try something like this

`ActiveRecord::Base.send :subclasses`
which works fine, but I'm not using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [`Mongoid::Config#models`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid_rails4/Mongoid/Config#models-instance_method):

> Get all the models in the application - this is everything that includes `Mongoid::Document`.

All `Config` methods can be accessed from the `Mongoid` module, so you can call:

```
Mongoid.models #=> [...]
```

Comment: `[Mongoid::GridFs::Fs::File, Mongoid::GridFs::Fs::Chunk, Invoice]` Only got this. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the edit btw.

Comment: @KumarAbinash I don't know. The method works for me as advertised, i.e. the array contains all classes with an `include Mongoid::Document` line.

Comment: @Kumar , this method only gives you the models that were used in the session that you are. So if access the rails console and call User.first for example, Mongoid.models will only return the User model.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` to list the ActiveRecord models.

For mongoDB you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862470/871580